# Given a dataframe with duplicated index, how can I merge together rows by reducing with combine_first method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

Consider the following input:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame with duplicate index values
data = {'A': [1, 2, None, 4, 5],
        'B': [None, None, 3, None, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

How can I reduce all duplicated-index rows by reducing all rows to a single row with method combine_first()?

Something like that:

```
df.groupby(df.index).agg(...) # the agg function should take the group and apply combine_first on each pair of rows until the result is reduced.
```

The output result should be (if we save the first value if not null)

```
{'A': [1, 2, 4],
 'B': [None, 3, 4]}
```

or (if we save the last value if not null)

```
{'A': [1, 2, 5],
 'B': [None, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a custom function, simply use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html):

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
     A    B
1  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  3.0
3  4.0  4.0
```

Or [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html):

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).last()
```

Output:

```
     A    B
1  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  3.0
3  5.0  4.0
```